# Worksheet_Change: Triggered by User or Macro

Tags: excel, vba

In my Change Event, I need to trap a cell's old value, so I use an Application.Undo. However I have a macro that makes changes, which obviously clears the Undo Stack, but still relies on the rest of the Change Event procedures.

Can't rely on the Selection Change Event because if the user is already on the cell, this Event doesn't fire.
Can't use a hidden/mirror sheet as my full application builds these sheets based on a Master Template. I'd have to duplicate the info for as many sheets that the user creates from the Master.

And using On Error Resume Next is kludgy code.

Is there a way to either check the Undo Stack or determine if the Change Event was caused by user interaction or my macro.

Here's a quick demo to show the issue:

**Sheet1 Code-Behind:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim NewValue As String
    Dim OldValue As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F3")) Is Nothing Then
        NewValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = Target.Value
        Target.Value = NewValue
        MsgBox "Changed from: " & OldValue & " to " & NewValue
    End If

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Standard Module Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MacroTest()
    'clears undo stack
    Sheet1.Range("F3").Value = "Macro Run"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd say there's nothing wrong with using On Error Resume Next to trap the error on calling `Application.Undo` - that's pretty much your only option and controlled/limited use of OERN is fine.  If it makes you nervous in your main method, create a small `CanUndo` function to factor out that part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the step after "NewValue = Target.Value". Add the logic in between these lines:

```
    NewValue = Target.Value
    On Error Resume Next ' Add this line of code
    Application.Undo
```